# How to edit the tree viewer element based on context menu selection

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I want to edit the tree viewer element based on my context menu option. Basically i need to update the element value which is displayed. If i double click on tree viewer element i was able to update the value, but through context menu also i should be able to do.

Sample code for adding the context menu:

```
 protected def void createContextMenu(Viewer viewer) {
    val MenuManager contextMenu = new MenuManager("Menu"); // $NON-NLS-1$
    contextMenu.setRemoveAllWhenShown(true);
    contextMenu.addMenuListener(new IMenuListener() {

        public override void menuAboutToShow(IMenuManager mgr) {
                fillContextMenu(mgr);
        }
    });

    val Menu menu = contextMenu.createContextMenu(viewer.getControl());
    viewer.getControl().setMenu(menu);

}

/**
 * Fill dynamic context menu
 * 
 * @param contextMenu
 */
protected def void fillContextMenu(IMenuManager contextMenu) {
    contextMenu.add(new GroupMarker(IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS));

    contextMenu.add(new Action("Rename") {

        public override void run() {
            val selectedElement = (treeViewer.selection as IStructuredSelection).firstElement
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What don't you understand here? You have the selected element in the tree, what do you want to do with it? What are you doing in the double click listener?

Comment: Hi @greg-449: I need to edit the selection element value. During the double click operation, i have added ColumnViewerEditorActivationStrategy to listen the Doubleclick event

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps or let me know otherwise

```
package myFolder;

import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILabelProviderListener;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ITreeContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TreeViewerColumn;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MenuEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.MenuListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TreeItem;

public class trying {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    shell.setSize(300,300);

    TreeViewer viewer = new TreeViewer(shell);
    viewer.getTree().setHeaderVisible(true);
    viewer.getTree().setLinesVisible(true);

    viewer.setContentProvider(new ITreeContentProvider () {

        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void inputChanged(Viewer arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public Object[] getChildren(Object arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object[] getElements(Object arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new String[]{"Hoshe","Irani"};
        }

        @Override
        public Object getParent(Object arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasChildren(Object arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }


    });
    viewer.setLabelProvider(new ILabelProvider(){

        @Override
        public void addListener(ILabelProviderListener arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void dispose() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLabelProperty(Object arg0, String arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void removeListener(ILabelProviderListener arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public Image getImage(Object arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public String getText(Object arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "hoshe";
        }


    });
    viewer.setInput("Hoshe");             

    Menu popupMenu = new Menu(viewer.getControl());
    MenuItem newItem = new MenuItem(popupMenu, SWT.CHECK);
    newItem.setText("New");
    MenuItem refreshItem = new MenuItem(popupMenu, SWT.CHECK);
    refreshItem.setText("Refresh");
    MenuItem deleteItem = new MenuItem(popupMenu, SWT.CHECK);
    deleteItem.setText("Delete");

    popupMenu.addMenuListener(new MenuListener() {

        @Override
        public void menuShown(MenuEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void menuHidden(MenuEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    TreeItem [] arr = viewer.getTree().getSelection();
                    for(MenuItem item2 : popupMenu.getItems()){
                        boolean bool1 = item2.getSelection();   
                            if(bool1){
                                arr[0].setText(item2.getText());
                                item2.setSelection(false);
                            }
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });

    viewer.getTree().setMenu(popupMenu);
    shell.open();
    while(!shell.isDisposed()){
        if(!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

}